# Touchable and data driven overlays (polygons) in a MKMapView with data from geoJson

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview, geojson, mkoverlay

I am trying to draw overlays with **MKOverlay** (polygon) on a **MKMapView** from a given **geoJson** file.

My code works fine. The polygons are displayed. I use the **MKGeoJSONDecoder**.
I would like to use the user's current location to display data from the current overlay. This data is also in the geoJson file as property. **Is that possible?**

Is it also possible to make the overlays touchable in order to display the data of the current overlay by touch?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "directions", ofType: "geojson") {
            do {
                let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)

                if let features = try? MKGeoJSONDecoder().decode(data) as? [MKGeoJSONFeature] {

                    for feature in features {

                        if let poly = feature.geometry[0] as? MKPolygon {
                            mapView.addOverlay(poly)
                        }

                        if let multiPoly = feature.geometry[0] as? MKMultiPolygon {
                            mapView.addOverlay(multiPoly)
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                // print errors
            }
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

        switch overlay {
        case is MKPolygon:
            let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: overlay as! MKPolygon)
            renderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
            renderer.lineWidth = 1
            return renderer
        case is MKMultiPolygon:
            let renderer = MKMultiPolygonRenderer(multiPolygon: overlay as! MKMultiPolygon)
            renderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.25)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
            renderer.lineWidth = 1
            return renderer
        default:
            return MKOverlayRenderer()
        }
    }
}
```